# Editing a new row in datagrid activates shortcuts without ALT is pressed

Tags: wpf, datagrid, shortcut, alt

I have the following Window defined:

```
<Window x:Class="ShortCutInTabControlproblem.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel>

    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="_1st Tab">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" />                
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="_2nd Tab">

        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

With the following code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>
                    {new Person() {Name = "John", Age = 39}, new Person() {Name = "Doe", Age = 34}};

        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

And finally the following "Model":

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The strangest thing happens when I try to add a row to the datagrid on the first tab ("1st Tab") and the first key I press is '2'. This will activate the second tab ("2nd tab"), as this has a shortcut defined.

If I edit an existing grid, e.g. the age of John and press '2', then nothing happens (except the age is changed to 2).

Is this a known bug and are there any known fixes? Do You know of a way to require Alt+'2' to be pressed, and not just '2'?

Please help me...

Thanks in advance
Søren Rokkedal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a know issue that is supposed to be fixed in a future release of .NET.

In the meantime you can use a custom TabItem to fix your problem :

```
public class MyTabItem : TabItem
{
    protected override void OnAccessKey(AccessKeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) != ModifierKeys.Alt)
        {
            return;
        }
        base.OnAccessKey(e);
    }
}
```

You can also write the following fix to solve the issue for all UIElements :

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UIElement), AccessKeyManager.AccessKeyPressedEvent, new AccessKeyPressedEventHandler(OnAccessKeyPressed));
```

where OnAccessKeyPressed would implement the same logic.

Comment: Thank You Sysyphe for the answer. It works like a charm.

A small note: The second solution (EventManager.RegisterClassHandler) requires .Net 4.5.

Comment: UPS, my bad. I misunderstood the new MSDN documentation for .Net 4.5 - It is indeed possible to do both in .Net 4.0